# Pass parameter to a minted contract

Tags: solidity, web3js

I am using `` and I have the following contract:

```
contract rNFT is ERC721Enumerable, Ownable {
  using Strings for uint256;

  string baseURI;
  string public baseExtension = ".json";
  uint256 public cost; // = 0.0 ether;
  uint256 public maxSupply = 99999999999999999999999;
  uint256 public maxMintAmount = 1;
  // bool public paused = false;
  bool public isInVault = false;
  string public notRevealedUri;

  constructor(
    string memory _name,
    string memory _symbol,
    string memory _initBaseURI,
    string memory _initNotRevealedUri,
    uint256 _cost
  ) ERC721(_name, _symbol) {
    setBaseURI(_initBaseURI);
    setNotRevealedURI(_initNotRevealedUri);
    setCost(_cost);
  }
```

When creating the contract on the testnet the initial parameters are passed via the constructor.

However, I am currently creating a form to upload an image and mint your own NFT.

Currently my javascript `claimNFT()` function looks like the following:

```
    const claimNFTs = () => {
        let cost = CONFIG.WEI_COST; // how much does the rNFT service cost
        let gasLimit = CONFIG.GAS_LIMIT;
        let totalCostWei = String(cost * mintAmount);
        let totalGasLimit = String(gasLimit * mintAmount);
        console.log("Cost: ", totalCostWei);
        console.log("Gas limit: ", totalGasLimit);
        setFeedback(`Minting your ${CONFIG.NFT_NAME}...`);
        setClaimingNft(true);
        blockchain.smartContract.methods
            .mint(mintAmount)
            .send({
                gasLimit: String(totalGasLimit),
                to: CONFIG.CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
                from: blockchain.account,
                value: totalCostWei,
            })
            .once("error", (err) => {
                console.log(err);
                setFeedback("Sorry, something went wrong please try again later.");
                setClaimingNft(false);
            })
            .then((receipt) => {
                console.log(receipt);
                setFeedback(
                    `WOW, the ${CONFIG.NFT_NAME} is yours! go visit Opensea.io to view it.`
                );
                setClaimingNft(false);
                dispatch(fetchData(blockchain.account));
            });
    };
```

Any suggestions how to uri of each nft individually when minting?

I appreciate your replies.

Answer (score 0):

You must make `token URL storage`, here is the openzeppelin contract code for making a ERC-721 contract with token URI storage:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC721, ERC721URIStorage, Ownable {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;

    Counters.Counter private _tokenIdCounter;

    constructor() ERC721("MyToken", "MTK") {}

    function safeMint(address to, string memory uri) public onlyOwner {
        uint256 tokenId = _tokenIdCounter.current();
        _tokenIdCounter.increment();
        _safeMint(to, tokenId);
        _setTokenURI(tokenId, uri);
    }

    // The following functions are overrides required by Solidity.

    function _burn(uint256 tokenId) internal override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage) {
        super._burn(tokenId);
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage)
        returns (string memory)
    {
        return super.tokenURI(tokenId);
    }
}
```

Also, if you want to initiate URI link (group of ERC-721 tokens), then add more URI's in future, then here is the code

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC721, ERC721URIStorage, Ownable {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;

    Counters.Counter private _tokenIdCounter;

    constructor() ERC721("MyToken", "MTK") {}

    function _baseURI() internal pure override returns (string memory) {
        return "ipfs:/<BaseURILink>";
    }

    function safeMint(address to, string memory uri) public onlyOwner {
        uint256 tokenId = _tokenIdCounter.current();
        _tokenIdCounter.increment();
        _safeMint(to, tokenId);
        _setTokenURI(tokenId, uri);
    }

    // The following functions are overrides required by Solidity.

    function _burn(uint256 tokenId) internal override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage) {
        super._burn(tokenId);
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage)
        returns (string memory)
    {
        return super.tokenURI(tokenId);
    }
}
```

NOTE: replace `ipfs:/<BaseURILink>` with URI link you want to initiate smart contract wit

Answer (score -1):

You will not be able to go off of Hashlips template if you are not the most educated on blockchain developing. To give you the answer you are wanting would be to create the file for you. I have created something like tis before I will show you what the handler function looks like.

I forgot to add the contract I am sorry this may help, you need a contract that creates NFTs not stores them.

You can also look at that website and see if I am even talking about the same idea you are talking about

[image: Code snippet of what it will look like for your handler]

[image: Contract Sample]

Comment: Thank you. However, I do not use hashlibs. I tried your above idea, but I do not get the  the return back from my mint function.